# Does the jQuery hoverIntent plugin work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

Is the [hoverIntent](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hoverIntent) plugin compatible with Internet Explorer? I'm having trouble plugging it into the following JavaScript:

```
if (jQuery.browser.msie === true) {
  jQuery('#top_mailing')
    .bind("mouseenter",function(){
      $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideDown('slow');
    })
    .bind("mouseleave",function(){
      $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideUp('slow');
    });
}
```

I'm using the following for other browsers but it's not functioning in IE7

```
$('#top_mailing').hoverIntent(
  function () {
    $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideDown('slow');
  }, 
  function () {
    $("#top_mailing_hidden").stop().slideUp('slow');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say yes since I'm using it on this page - http://trailroc.com/?p=team
I checked 7 and 8, not sure if it works in IE6 because I don't care.

I'm using jQuery 1.3.1 though: